# Angular 6 svg add class to path on click

Tags: jquery, svg, click, angular6

I am trying to add class into my svg map inside angular onclick event:
I have a working code it works inside ngOnInit() but when I add same code inside a click event function it is not working:

My  ngOnInit code is:

```
   ngOnInit() {

      let a = document.getElementById("biharsvg")  as HTMLObjectElement;;

         a.addEventListener("load", function() {
              var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
              var wchamparan = svgDoc.getElementById("wchamparan");

               console.log(wchamparan);

              wchamparan.onclick = function() {
               alert("hello");
                }
     })
}
```

This code is working fine I can see the log but when I am doing this in a click event on a button whose code is:

```
 click() {

 alert("hello");

 let a = document.getElementById("biharsvg")  as HTMLObjectElement;

 // var wchamparan = svgDoc.getElementById("wchamparan");
 // element.classList.add("mystyle");
    a.addEventListener("load", function() {
         let svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
         let wchamparan = svgDoc.getElementById("wchamparan");
         wchamparan.classList.add("mystyle");

         console.log("hello");
})
}
```

Here I can see the alert message I can also see what is inside a but a.addEventListener("load", function() I can't see anything. Why this is not working what is the difference between ngOnInit() and onclick function. What is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  tried many things to make it work when I remove addEventListener then it worked so my solution code is:

```
appendToContainer() {
let map = document.getElementById("biharsvg") as HTMLObjectElement;
let svgDoc = map.contentDocument; // should be fine
let echamparan = svgDoc.getElementById("echamparan");
echamparan.classList.add("mystyle");
console.log(echamparan);
}
```

So the problem was I guess add event listener.